# Finding the least square solution with 3 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Am I correct in saying that my Design matrix is

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & -1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
and my observation vector is Z

\begin{bmatrix}
    3 \\
    -6  \\
    6  \\
    0 
  \end{bmatrix}
 then I would solve by setting X transpose * X = X transpose * Z

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** *Almost* right! However, you don't want the column of $1$'s in your design matrix, because you *don't have an intercept term* in your plane equation. Therefore, your design matrix should just have **two** columns (and still four rows). Also, you appear to have made a mistake in copying in the last $y$ value for your design matrix. Once you have fixed up your design matrix $X$, you would find $c_1, c_2$ by solving $$X^T X \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2\end{bmatrix} = X^T Z.$$

Comment: what would you an equation look like with intercept terms?

Comment: It would be like $z = \color{red}{c_0} + c_1 x + c_2 y$. The $c_0$ would be the intercept term. There is no $c_0$ in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to fit a plane that passes through the origin, there is no intercept term.

We do not need to introduce the intercept column. That is remove the first column of your proposed design matrix and proceed to solve for $c$ in  $$X^TXc = X^TZ$$